# When using select(), can i add same descriptor in both readfds and writefds set?

Tags: c, sockets, select

My program is going to use a single socket to read and write. Messages from multiple clients will be written to the same socket and the responses received will be multiplexed back to the respective clients.

When making select() call, can I set the same single fd in readfds and writefds sets in order to detect whether the socket is ready for read or write? I plan to read or write on the socket based upon the the status that select() would return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and that's a very typical thing to do.